# What are differences between XMLHttpRequest and HttpRequest

Tags: php, zend-framework, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

In Zend Framework and other framework such as Symfony, there is a method named isXMLHttpRequest() to determine this is XMLHttpRequest or not. I wonder that how can framework or PHP distinguish between XmlHttpRequest and HttpRequest?

```
if($this->_request->isXmlHttpRequest())
{
   //code here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.request.html#zend.controller.request.http.ajax):

> Zend_Controller_Request_Http has a rudimentary method for detecting AJAX requests: isXmlHttpRequest(). This method looks for an HTTP request header X-Requested-With with the value 'XMLHttpRequest'; if found, it returns TRUE.