# True difference between HttpRequest and XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, networking, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

### Note before reading

This is not a duplicate of [what-are-differences-between-xmlhttprequest-and-httprequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499062/what-are-differences-between-xmlhttprequest-and-httprequest)
And for info, I tried [this lib](https://github.com/jbeuckm/node-XMLHttpRequest/blob/master/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js) without success, because it copies the structure of the XMLHttpRequest but doesn't actually act like it.

---

I wonder what is the true network difference between `HttpRequest` from Node and `XMLHttpRequest` from a browser.

If I just watch the XMLHttpRequest inside chrome's devtools, I can't see any `X-Requested-with` header in the request.

Besides, there's an online service that is behind CloudFlare's WAF with custom rules. If I make the request with `XMLHttpRequest`, it just works, but I do it with `https.request` it fails being firewalled by CF.

I need to do it with `HttpRequest` so I can configure a proxy.

What is the network difference between the two, and how could I simulate a XMLHttpRequest from a HttpRequest ? And is that even possible ?
I watched the source of chromium [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink.git/+/99b8c9800ac123eddc3e199088d22569c5294b22/Source/core/xml/XMLHttpRequest.cpp) but can't find anything interesting.

Maybe it differs from the IO layers ? TCP handshake ?

Advices required. Thanks

---

### Edit

Here is the XMLHttpRequest (working)

```
let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("post", "https://haapi.ankama.com/json/Ankama/v2/Api/CreateApiKey", true);
req.withCredentials = true;
req.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8');
req.setRequestHeader('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate, br');
req.onload = function() {
    console.log(req.response)
};
req.send("login=smallladybug949&password=Tl9HDKWjusopMWy&long_life_token=true");
```

The same, as cURL (not passing the CF's firewall)

```
curl 'URL' \
-H 'origin: null' \
-H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' \
-H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Z988 Build/MMB29M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Mobile Safari/537.36' \
-H 'content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8' \
-H 'accept: application/json' \
-H 'authority: URL.com' \
--data-binary 'login=123&password=def' \
--compressed
```

Here is the HttpRequest (not passing the CF's firewall)

```
let opts = url.parse(URL);
opts.method = post;
opts.headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; SM-G960F Build/R16NW) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.137 Mobile Safari/537.36'
}
let req = https.request(opts, function (res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.body = "";
    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
      res.body += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', (chunk) => {
      try {
        res.body = JSON.parse(res.body);
      } catch (e) {
        return reject(res.body); // error, http 403 / 1020 error from CF (custom FW rule)
      }
      console.log(res.body); // we'll not reach this
    });
});
req.on('error', e => {
  console.error('error', e);
});
req.write("login=abc&password=def");
req.end();
```

---

### Edit 2

After several tests, the curl command is working, the XHR works too, but with Postman or HttpRequest, it fails.
Here is a video of the postman vs curl : https://streamable.com/81s57
The curl command in the video is this one :

```
curl -X POST \
  https://haapi.ankama.com/json/Ankama/v2/Api/CreateApiKey \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' \
  -H 'accept-language: fr' \
  -H 'authority: haapi.ankama.com' \
  -H 'content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8' \
  -H 'origin: null' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; SM-G960F Build/R16NW) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.137 Mobile Safari/537.36' \
  -d 'login=smallladybug949&password=Tl9HDKWjusopMWy&long_life_token=true'
```

(this is a test account so I don't need it and you can make tests with it). You can either add `--compressed` flag to the curl request to decompress it or pipe it to `gunzip`.

---

### Edit 3 (final)

I found out that it was due to the misused (for CF) TLS protocol. By downgrading curl which is using OpenSSL/1.1.0f, the calls just work. But since OpenSSL/1.1.0g they don't.
You can read more about OpenSSL changelogs [here](https://www.openssl.org/news/openssl-1.1.0-notes.html)

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668449/xmlhttprequest-vs-httprequest

Comment: I did before posting this, but it does not answer the real question, these are the words explaining, but I need the technical details. What does 'fetch a resource' mean in the network ? Is it still a socket connection ? Surely, because every connection has a socket, but what *is* the true difference that makes the request being blocked by the CF's firewall. On their website, they talk about "how the request is made". Maybe there's a hint in that.

Comment: @Sw0ut The XHR request from browser sends various headers like "User-Agent" and "Referrer", but that's not the case with request made from Node server, ie. HttpRequest. 
The origin on the server actually used for security purposes which detects the source of the request.

Comment: @AkanshGulati True, but I sent the User-Agent header also with the HttpRequest and it was still blocked. I made the exact same request on the human point of view. Same URL, same headers, same parameters. I'll edit my question to add more details on how I did the requests on both sides.

Comment: @Sw0ut it will be great if you can share both the requests as cUrl so that all things like Headers, Method type, Body, Query Params, Protocol, Pathname can be compared. 
Also, I hope you know about pre-flight requests which are made by browser for any cross-origin request.

Comment: I don't have a curl equivalent for the second request, but I can reproduce with Postman. I've added the authority header because I did not see it, but still a 403 error from cloudflare.I don't know what more to do. By doing the cURL extract from the working XHR, it fails in 403 also.

Comment: Where did you get the curl equivalent for the XMLHttpRequest? From the browser's devtools? It's very weird that you can't reproduce the results of the browser request via curl. If you make the same request twice from the browser, do devtools show that the equivalent curl request is the same? And running curl always fails while the browser request always succeeds?

Comment: @Nickolay yes, I right clicked on the request, then copied it as cURL. No, it is not the same because the first time, there are no cookie, and the second time there are cloudflares cookies. If I clear cache and cookie on the browser, it still works, but with curl, without cookies it doesn't work. With cookies it works because there is a cf_uid and cf_bm which allows you to "bypass" cloudflare security. But those cookies are temporary.

Comment: OK. So each time you clear cache/cookies in the browser, the request works (though it is "without cookies"), when copied as curl it looks the same every time, but the curl version never works? That would be weird, and at that point I'd fire up Wireshark...

Comment: Exactly ! I tried it again to be sure i'm not a jackass, but i'm serious, the copied request as curl (or powershell in my case) gives a 403 error...

Comment: @Nickolay if you don't believe me, I made a video of it : https://streamable.com/oiu2c

Comment: Your video doesn't show _two_ clean attempts in the browser resulting in the same invoke-webrequest, but it doesn't look like the request would change. I'd try curl too, and what's the 601 status code you get in the browser? Is this a publicly available server? Can you post the specific JS code others could try?

Comment: Indeed but there's no need to make 2 requests for it to work. the 601 status code is what is returning the service's API (bad credentials).
Hmm the curl version works without any cookie : `curl 'https://haapi.ankama.com/json/Ankama/v2/Api/CreateApiKey' -H 'origin: null' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'accept-language: fr' -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 Mobile' -H 'content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8' -H 'accept: application/json' -H 'authority: haapi.ankama.com' --data-binary 'login=test&password=test&long_life_token=false' --compressed` I don't know what to think...

Comment: You can try with Postman for example, it won't work. What is the difference ? The `--compressed` flag does not interfere the request and the `--data-binary` flag is curl specific to include data in the body... Why ?

Comment: @Nickolay I added an edit in my question, plus a video. Check it please. Thanks

Comment: OK, I can reproduce (edited the "Here is the XMLHttpRequest (working)" to be the real example, not a redacted one). When I copy that as curl I get a different command than what you posted (something closer to Edit 2), critically including the `Accept-Language` header. Omitting it results in a 403. But for me, neither the curl command I get from Firefox, nor your command from Edit 2 work unless I pass `--cert-status` to curl (libcurl/7.65.3 OpenSSL/1.0.2s). [`openssl s_client`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42810371/1026) with the same HTTP headers as `curl -v` prints works out of the box.

Comment: So lack of certain HTTP headers (`Accept-Language`) and TLS options ([`--cert-status`](https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl-tls.html#ocsp-stapling)) cause the 403. I'll have to Google to see which of these node trips on.

Comment: **You're leaking your password...**

Comment: @zhengliw you're correct. This was a throwaway account anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I discussed in the comments, I can reproduce: the XMLHttpRequest example from the first "Edit" works (HTTP status = 200), while the "copy as cURL" version of it returns 403 from Cloudfare.

**Adding [`--cert-status`](https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl-tls.html#ocsp-stapling) to curl makes it work for me, so it seems that Cloudfare analyzes TLS-level communication when deciding to deny a request.**

Your curl command from the first Edit has a few other differences from the version I get when using "Copy as cURL":

- `curl 'URL'` instead of `https://haapi.ankama.com/json/Ankama/v2/Api/CreateApiKey` obviously fails, please don't make it harder to reproduce your results.
- `-H 'origin: null'` vs `-H 'Origin: https://localhost:4443' -H 'Referer: https://localhost:4443/test_http.html'`  - this doesn't make a difference.
- I have a few additional headers `-H 'DNT: 1' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Cookie: __cfduid=dcf1b80eef19562054c9b64f79139509e1566138746'` that don't make a difference either.
- Varying `-H 'user-agent:` - doesn't affect Cloudfare either
- You have an extra `-H 'authority: URL.com'` (with placeholder in place of the real domain), and this doesn't make a difference either.
- Whether the POST data is correct `--data-binary 'login=123&password=def'` only affects the API results; doesn't affect the 403.
- **The missing `-H 'Accept-Language:` header causes the 403 from Cloudfare.**

So you could try adding the missing `Accept-Language` to the Node version to see if it helps.

My version of Node doesn't send `Extension: status_request` in the TLS Client Hello (which seems to be the difference between curl invocations with or without `--cert-status`), and I don't see how you would enable it. At this point I'd try contacting support if possible or falling back to calling curl from node.

P.S. while debugging it I attempted to compare the Wireshark captures of curl vs browser (node doesn't support `SSLKEYLOGFILE`, [forcing you to jump through hoops, so I didn't even try checking how its capture looks](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/2363#issuecomment-495929228)). There are so many minor differences, that trying to reverse engineer the rules that Cloudfare uses would be very time-consuming. `--cert-status` was a lucky guess.

The SSL Client Hello across Firefox/curl/node are very different:
**Firefox** [image: firefox 70]
**curl** [image: curl --cert-status]
**node11** [image: node 11]

Comment: Good catch for the TLS.
It's kind of weird but if I add `--cert-status` in the curl command, it fails. (`curl: (91) OCSP response verification failed`)
I guess Postman is based on node, which is why it does not work either. As seen in the video I made in the Edit 2 section, the `Accept-Language` is already included in the request. I tried also in the node version and I still get 403. So your guess is about that `Extension: status_request` in the Client Hello not being sent by node, but how to be sure, can curl manage this kind of tricky request ?

Comment: Look, the main point is that there are lots of differences between the various clients (see the screenshots I've added - and it's just one TLS Client Hello request!), so reverse engineering the protection rules is next to impossible. For instance, disabling the `status_request` in Firefox (via security.ssl.enable_ocsp_stapling) doesn't seem to break it. Don't try to get node to look like a browser without knowing the exact rules, use the client that works for you - you've managed to get curl working, albeit with a different invocation than the one that works for me.

Comment: Fine, it answers the question, even if it does not solve the problem. I'll figure this out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i suppose the curl and node HttpRequest are missing a valid `origin` header. the XMLHttpRequest uses the browser engine, therefore sends and validates cross-origin-policy and specifiy those headers as well.

This is used to secure websites from accessing API-endpoints of other websites they don't belong to. Aka the web admin can specify origin-domains, which can communicate to your API. All http-rest-requests browser implementations send and validate the origin header.

Curl and HttpRequest are not browser / website's technology. Have a look at `CORS`,`Same-origin-policy` and `origin-header`. I suppose this will clarify the issue.

Comment: The point is that the endpoint is accessed via a mobile application made with cordova. The origin is `null` because the endpoint is accessed via a `file://` URL. Maybe you are right when you talk about Origin header, but I tried with several URLs (null, base URL of the API, file:///www/index.html) and did not succeed. // Edit : and the copied cURL from the working XHR fails, the origin is included in it.