# unable to scrape https://angel.co/

Tags: python, curl, scrapy, python-requests, scrapy-shell

I am trying to use scrape few pages of this website.

I have tried various stack overflow answers regarding this website and none worked. All pages from website only returns 403. I have tried changing ip and changing useragents

```
headers = {
            "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3",
            "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,ru-RU;q=0.8,ru;q=0.7",
            "cache-control": "no-cache",
            "pragma": "no-cache",
            "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1"
        }

yield scrapy.Request('https://angel.co/login',callback=self.parse, method='GET',headers=headers)
```

How can I make my spider successfully scrape this website? I have checked this website works well even if javascript is disabled but still cant scrape :(

Comment: I recently [helped look into Cloudfare protections on another site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57436880/true-difference-between-httprequest-and-xmlhttprequest), and it turned out to depend on the TLS metadata sent by the client. You might get some debugging ideas reading through the comments as well as the answer there.

Comment: sure It looks interesting, thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

This website is using cloudflare ddos protection service.

Try to use some headers like `user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36` in your headers

You must convince server that you are a browser, not a scraper.

Some cloudflare ddos protection need to run javascript. and some others need captcha that machine cannot answer it

First, write your response in a file and look at that to find what kind of protection is that. Second, Try to handle that due to the problem

Comment: You are right. I didn't think of checking the response. The genius cloudfare is throwing captcha

Comment: So, you are arrested by cloudflare like me now :))

Comment: yes :(. trying cfscrape module and still no hope :(

Comment: cfscrape works for js protection I think. Captcha protection has no escape path :)

Comment: You sure about selenium?

Comment: yes cloudfare didnt throw captcha at me while using this website in broswer. i even tried with js disabled. but selenium is dead slow

Comment: scratch that, cloudfare just threw captcha at me while in browser:(

Comment: That's because your ip address. Are you using VPN or something?