# Presign Video.js XMLHttpRequest Requests for HLS (.m3u8) Streaming of Playlists / Segments

Tags: amazon-s3, video.js

**My Question**

How do I change the video.js XHR request **uri** to be S3 presigned URLs?

**The Problem**

I generate an AWS presigned URL server-side and send it to the HTML template.

```
<video-js id="lesson_video" class="video-js" controlsList="nodownload">
    <source src="https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/my-unique-bucket-here/videos/master.m3u8?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIA#####NJQHSC&amp;Signature=ep8L%2By#####ard4%3D&amp;Expires=1688435441" type="application/x-mpegURL"/>
    <p class="vjs-no-js">
        To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a
        web browser that <a href="https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
    </p>
</video-js>
```

When the page loads, the initial `master.m3u8` file loads with a status code 200, but all attempts to get / load the other playlists / segments result in a `403 Forbidden`.

[image: attempts to get .m3u8 segments]

**My Understanding**

When the [withCredentials](https://github.com/videojs/http-streaming/blob/main/README.md#withcredentials) property is set to true, all XHR requests for manifests and segments would have withCredentials set to true as well. **It doesn't seem to be working and I have no idea where to start in trouble-shooting it.**

```
var player = videojs("lesson_video", {
    ...
    html5: {
      vhs: {
        withCredentials: true,
      },
    },
  }
```

Other Notes:

```
Version: "video.js": "^8.3.0",
```

Comment: Does anything in here help? :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57436880/true-difference-between-httprequest-and-xmlhttprequest